Formalize a proof for the existence complete graph minor in a graph
About a year ago on this site I saw a theorem + proof regarding the existence of $K_m$ minor in a graph, but I can't seem to find it now so I need someone's help to track it down or to replicate it. The theorem goes like this:
Given $G = (V,E)$ an undirected, simple graph, a complete graph $K_m$ minor exists in G if and only if exist $X_1,...,X_m \subseteq V$ such that:

$\forall_{1\leq{i}<j\leq{m}}$ $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$.

$\forall_{1\leq{i}\leq{m}}$ $G' = (X_i, E \cap X_i \times X_i)$ is connected.

$\forall_{1\leq{i}<j\leq{m}}$ $\exists_{x \in X_i,y \in X_j}$ $(x,y) \in E$


In other words, only if $m$ disjoint subsets of $V$ in $G$ exist, such that every subset is connected (that way we'll be able to contract them together as part of the minor actions) and each subset needs to be connected to the other subsets after the contractions, we'll be able to form the complete graph $K_m$ in the end.
I believe that this theorem can be explained using induction on the size of $m$, but before I'll try to do it I want to see if the proof already exists.
Also, on the off chance that it doesn't exist for some reason, I'd like some tips regarding how do I write this proof in a formal way, enough for an academic paper.
Any help would be appreciated!

Some notation before the answer:

For a graph $G$, $V(G)$ is the vertex set of $G$ and $E(G)$ is the edge set of $G$.
I am using $xy$ or $yx$ instead of $(x,y)$ to denote an edge, for brevity.
For a graph $G$ and a vertex subset $X \subseteq V(G)$, $G[X]$ denotes the subgraph of $G$ induced by $X$.

A more general version of the theorem is true. You can replace $K_m$ with any graph $H$ and restate it as done below. In fact, this is also used as an alternate definition sometimes.
Theorem. Let $G$ and $H$ be any simple undirected graphs. Let $V(H):=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. $H$ is a minor of $G$ if and only if there exist $X_1,...,X_n \subseteq V(G)$ such that:

$\forall~i,j~(i\neq j) \in [n]$, $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$ i.e., the $X_i$'s are disjoint.

$\forall~ i \in [n]$, $G[X_i]$ is connected.

$\forall~ij \in E(H)$, $\exists~a \in X_i$ and $b \in X_j$ such that $ab \in E(G)$.


Proof $(\impliedby)$:
For each $i \in [n]$, $G[X_i]$ is connected and hence, has a spanning tree $T_i$. Let $G_1$ be the graph obtained from $G$ by contracting every edge in $E(T_1)$. There is exactly one (contraction) vertex in $G_1$ that is not originally a vertex of $G$. Let $x_1$ denote that vertex.
Similarly we may obtain the graphs $G_{i+1}$ from $G_i$ for each $i \in \{2,3,\dots,n\}$. At each step, we may identify the unique vertex $x_i$ since all the $X_i$'s are disjoint. Finally we obtain $G'$ from $G_n$ by deleting all the vertices except $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.
Now it suffices to prove that $H$ is a subgraph of $G'$. Let $ij$ be any edge of $H$. From point 3 we know $\exists~a \in X_i,~b \in X_j$ such that $ab \in E(G)$. Observe that $x_ix_j$ is an edge of $G'$. $\square$
Proof $(\implies)$: We will prove by induction on $|V(G)|+|E(G)|$. If $G \cong H$, via a bijection $f:V(H) \rightarrow V(G)$, then the sets $X_i:=\{f(i)\}$ for each $i \in [n]$ satisfy the required conditions. Now, if $G \ncong H$, then by definition of minor, there exists a series of graphs $(G_0=G,G_1,G_2,\dots,G_k=H)$ such that for each $i \in [k]$, $G_i$ is obtained from $G_{i-1}$ by one of the following three operations:

Deletion of a vertex.
Deletion of an edge.
Contraction of an edge.

By definition, $G_1$ also contains $H$ as a minor. Also regardless of what operation is used to obtain $G_1$ from $G$, $|V(G_1)|+|E(G_1)|$ is strictly less than $|V(G)|+|E(G)|$. Therefore, by induction hypothesis, there is a collection of subsets $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n \subseteq V(G_1)$ that satisfies all the three conditions. For a better readability (in my opinion), let us denote $G_1$ using $G'$.
Case 1: $G'$ is obtained from $G$ either by deleting a vertex or by deleting an edge.
Observe that the sets $X_i:=Y_i$ for each $i \in [n]$ satisfy the required conditions.
Case 2: $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by contracting an edge $e$ whose ends are $u$ and $v$.
Let $w$ denote the contraction vertex in $G'$.
If $w \notin Y_i$ for any $i$ then let $X_i:=Y_i$ for each $i \in [n]$. Observe that the sets $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ satisfy the required conditions.
Otherwise if $w \in Y_i$ for some $i$, adjust notation so that $w \in Y_1$. Define $X_1:=Y_1-\{w\} \cup \{u,v\}$ and $X_i:=Y_i$ for each $i \in \{2,3,\dots,n\}$.
Condition 1: Since $Y_i$'s are disjoint, it is clear that $X_i$'s are also disjoint.
Condition 2: Note that the edge $e$ is in $G[X_1]$ and that $G'[Y_1]$ may be obtained by contracting the edge $e$ of $G[X_1]$. If $J$ is any disconnected graph and $J'$ is obtained by contracting an edge of $J$, clearly $J'$  is also disconnected. Therefore, $G[X_1]$ must be connected. Also, for each $i \in \{2,3,\dots,n\}$, observe that $G[X_i]=G'[X_i]$ and hence $G[X_i]$ is connected.
Condition 3: Note that each edge of $G'$ that is not incident with $w$ is also an edge of $G$. From this and the fact that $X_i=Y_i$ for each $i \neq 1$, we may conclude that for any edge of $H$ whose both ends are distinct from $1$, the required condition is satisfied. Now, for any edge of $H$ whose one of the ends is $1$, say $1i$, we know that there exists an $a \in Y_1$ and $b \in Y_i($recall that $Y_i=X_i)$ such that $ab \in E(G')$. If $a \neq w$, then $ab \in E(G)$ as well. If $a = w$, then at least one of $ub$ and $vb$ is an edge of $G$ since otherwise, it contradicts the fact that $wb \in E(G')$. Therefore, it is true that $\exists~a \in X_1$ and $b \in X_i$ such that $ab \in E(G)$.
Therefore, $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ satisfy the required conditions. $\square$
